# findViewById return null for view from layout

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have some strange problem, with the MapView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="my-api-key"/>
```

And `mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);`  return null for me. But MapView displayed normaly. What i'm doing wrong?

UPD: There is my class

```
public class WayMapActivity extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.maplayout);

    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
  }
```

Comment: calling that line *after* setContentView()?

Comment: Sometimes it is solved by cleaning the project

Comment: Also, does your class extends MapActivity?

Comment: Post some of your Java-source.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `setContentView(layout)` before `findViewById`?

Then try to clean and rebuild your project. Sometimes it is necessary to rebuild R

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project. sometimes it is necessary to rebuild R

Comment: Thanks. Clean project help to me.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Such problems can kill much time and cause brain damage :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me from time to time.

1. Remove the gen folder
2. Do a project clean
3. Re-run